# How to insert an imported image into an object in react

Tags: reactjs

I want to insert my img in my object (ReactJs)

I created an images file in my components files, I inserted two images.

I import the images

```
import converse from '../images/converse.png';
import samsung from '../images/samsung.png';
```

And now i want to use it in my object "products"

File Products :

```
const products = [
    { id:1, name:'Converse', description: 'Stan Smith', price: '95€', image: {src:converse} },
    { id:2, name:'Galaxy note Ultra', description: 'Téléphone Samsung', price: '1249€', image: {src:samsung} },
];
```

I call it in Product File

```
const Product = ({ product }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return (
        <Card className={classes.root}>
          <CardActionArea>
            <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={product.image} title={product.name} />
...
```

No error in the terminal.
This method does'nt work, i can't see the pictures.

How can I do ?

Comment: `image={product.image}` should be `image={product.image.src}` in `CardMedia`. Voting to close as unreproducible or caused by typo.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the object incorrectly. Add src to the object reference

```
  <CardMedia className={classes.media} image={product.image.src} title={product.name} />
```

Comment: I applied this.
React gives me the following error : TypeError : Cannot read property 'src' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I failed to load the images from the images document, but with the database it works like this :

```
<CardMedia image={item.media.source} alt={item.name} className={classes.media} />
```

Finnaly, It works with the database.